# Customizing GeoExplorer?

Tags: boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I'm just beginning to play with BoundlessGeo's GeoExplorer interface. I'm trying to figure out if I can customize it for use in-house. We basically need an intra-net type web mapping app to display various data layers (client project info, location, etc.). We need to do some custom queries, and there;s interest in a tabbed identify display.

Anyone know if it can be customized in such ways?

I'm finding the documentation kind of lacking, and this seems like a logical place to turn for answers.